# <s:if> tag condition not working for session variables in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am facing a peculiar issue for last 2 days, but could not find the cause.

I have a `<s:if`> tag in JSP file to check if the given boolean variable is `true`. If yes, I am displaying the menu.

I am checking 4 different variable of which 3 variables are working except 1. If any one of the variables `superAdmin, admin and requester` is `true`, then the list is displayed. But if the variable `person` is `true`, then the list is not shown.

I tried to print the value of the variable on the screen using `<s:hidden...>`, its printing the value as `TRUE`.

The variable is set as `true` and is passed to the UI.

Still, the `<s:if>` tag is not checking the boolean variable `person`, and so the list is not displayed on the screen.

```jsp
<s:if test="%{#session.userDetails.superAdmin || #session.userDetails.admin || #session.userDetails.person || #session.userDetails.requester}">
    <li><a href="../displays/MeasurementsByAdministrator.action" onclick="javascript:startCfaPB()">Member Measurements</a></li>
</s:if>
```

Comment: I think you must have a typo then

Comment: @ScaryWombat, do you see the typo in the attached code? I did search using the word if its due to the typo. Its exactly same.

Comment: @Anand Do you have any errors? What do you mean *the if condition is not working*?

Comment: @RomanC, I do not get any errors. I meant the IF clause is not working for the variable person (that has boolean value true).

Comment: @Anand See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, you say that the list shouldn't be shown if the variable `person` is `true`, otherwise it should be shown when its `false`.

Ergo, the if-condition should be `!#session.userDetails.person` , hence the `!`.

Comment: I said, if any of the 4 variables are true, then the list should be displayed. In this case, it is working for 3 variable but not for the variable 'person'. You misunderstood it. Requirement is if any of the 4 variables is true, so 'person' should be true and then the list should be shown. Thanks for your comment anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<s:if test="#session.userDetails.superAdmin || #session.userDetails.admin || #session.userDetails.person || #session.userDetails.requester">
    <li><a href="../displays/MeasurementsByAdministrator.action" onclick="javascript:startCfaPB()">Member Measurements</a></li>
</s:if>
```

Comment: That would evaluate to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should check if this works then you have problems with the return type of the variable.

```jsp
<s:if test="%{#session.userDetails.person == true}">
    <li><a href="../displays/MeasurementsByAdministrator.action" onclick="javascript:startCfaPB()">Member Measurements</a></li>
</s:if>
```